# Compression vs. redundancy: do they cancel each other out?

Tags: linux, tar, gzip, bzip2

Does it make sense to compress a tarball (or any kind of file, really), e.g., using `gzip` or `bzip2`, while at the same time creating redundancy files for it, e.g., a `par2` file?

The context is that I am reasoning about how to best backup my personal files.
My #1 priority is to avoid data loss due to bitrot, hence, the `par2` files.
Compression would be nice but is not my main concern.

The reason I am doubting the combined application of a compression algorithm and a erasure code algorithm is that the former works by eliminating redundancy (thereby creating smaller files) while the latter works by adding redundancy (thereby adding the capability to perform data recovery operations).
Don't they cancel each other out?

Is this a reasonable assumption or am I missing something here?

Comment: compression eliminates redundancy, yes, but for most files that's not the sort of redundancy that readily allows rebuilding the data if it gets corrupted. Something explicitly made for error correction would be made to make that easy. In any case, you could try what happens? With compression and without it, what the resulting size of the data is, and how long the processing takes.

Comment: I think they could cancel in terms of space, but not in terms of probability of data loss. Compression will remove some inherent redundancy, but a general purpose data recovery algorithm won't know how to rebuild your data in the case of bit error based on that inherent redundancy. For example say you have some string you need to backup `AAAABBBB`. It has some redundancy, you could compress it to something like `4A4B`. If you get some bit error in the original string and find `ACAABBBB`, the underlying redundancy isn't actually useful for recovery from the error.